Secure Keyboard Entry on Terminal is Stuck (MacOS Sequoia 15.2)
My Terminal seems to be stuck on "Secure Keyboard Entry". Clicking the menu item does not remove the check mark, defaults correctly shows that it is disabled (see screenshot). I've restarted the computer, restarted terminal, logged in and out, defaults write toggled the option.
Anybody know of any other way to disable it? It's interfering with my keybindings. This is a fresh issue as of MacOS Sequoia, was fine in MacOS 14.


Please quit Terminal and clear the saved application state by holding down the Shift key while double-clicking the app icon. If there's no change, quit again and move the preferences file to the Desktop. Any change now?

No luck unfortunately. Could this be a security profile issue? This is a company computer

That would make sense.
